# The page isn't redirecting properly - .htaccess file issue

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a problem with my .htaccess file.
Everything was working fine till I made some changes (added multi language handling):

Before:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(index.html)$ http://my-site.pl/ [R=301,L]
```

What I have added at the end of the file:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (pl) [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.html [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (en) [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.en.html [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} (jp) [NC]
RewriteRule .* index.jp.html [R,L]
```

I want to redirect all countries to theirs pages changing only (..) in my page url: http://my-site.pl/index.(..).html as in the above code.

I can't find where is the problem.

Error from Firefox browser:

> The page isn't redirecting properly. Firefox has detected that the
>   server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will
>   never complete.

EDIT:
After changes (still not work) full .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.html$).+$ / [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} en [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.en.html [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} jp [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.jp.html [R,L]

ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in 3rd rule that is redirecting to `index.html` and 2nd rule is redirecting `index.html` to `/` thus causing a redirect loop.

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ / [R=301,L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(?!index\.html$).+$ / [NC,R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} en [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.en.html [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} jp [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.jp.html [R,L]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache while testing.

Comment: Unfortunately still not working... the same error... every time cache cleared

Comment: still the same error is visible. tested on firefox and on internet explorer on mobile phone

Comment: It's something wrong with the pl redirect rule. Without this one everything is working but unfortunately all pages are redirected to en

Comment: Try updated rules again. If it still doesn't work then I suggest you post your full .htaccess in question and I will check it tomorrow morning.

Comment: i've added full .htaccess file with your changes to my post

Comment: Your .htaccess looks fine. Test in Chrome dev tool with caching disabled and check in Networking tab what are 301/302 redirect URLs you get.